# How to copy the value of a cell that contains a formula into another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

In Column A, I use a API that goes out to the web and returns a stock price.

I want to then copy just the stock price (not the formula) automatically into the cell next to it.  I  know I can copy special but I want this to occur automatically.  I'm looking for a Macro to do this.

Thanks

Comment: with vba, otherwise it is manual.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub Demo    
 columns("a").copy
 range("b1").pastespecial xlpastevalues
End Sub
```